# jquery is escape brackets when brackets are in value of variable breaking my addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to dynamically added input elements.

```
   $(function(){

 //the elements that are added dynamically.

 $('#addItem').click(function(){
      var form = "<tr id='"+i+"'><td>Quantity</td>
                     <td><input class='qty quan total chk' 
                                type='text' id='qty["+i+"]'   
                                name='qty["+i+"]'>
                    </td>";
 });

 //when user click submitThis button, this checks for blanks
   $(document).on('click','#submitThis',function(){
                    var error = 0;
                    $(".chk").each(function(){
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            if ($(this).val().length < 1){
                                $('#'+id).addClass('error');
                                error++;
                            }
                    });
           });
```

Im guessing this seems to fail because the var id contains brackets and gets all buggy.  the inputs need to be arrays for form post, because it could be a ton of inputs and is much easier on the processing side. I know the elements are added properly and I am listening properly because if i do an alert after the addClass I see the value of the input if i add some data, so it makes very little sense to me why the class is not being added.  The class is added to other fields that are not dynamically added. I know the if statement returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the element you're trying to select (`this`) just use it.

```
$(this).addClass('error');
```

alternately you could escape the brackets

```
$('#'+id.replace('[','\\[').replace(']','\\]')).addClass('error');
```